# Lattice barchart colour - fade from dark to light

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

I am using lattice to make a bar chart inside RStudio. Below is my code.

```
my_cols <- c("dark blue", "blue", "light blue") 

barchart(x = CourseTitle ~ avgCourse,
         data = avgCourseScoreLessThan3,
         col = my_cols,
         main = "Title",
         ylab = "Courses")
```

Which looks like this

[image]

However, rather than manually indicate the colours of the bar chart, I'd prefer to have one colour, say blue, which then fades automatically from dark blue to faint blue for each bar in the chart.

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I'd really appreciate any help or advice from anyone.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `scale_colour_brewer()`. Check below example.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
 (d <- ggplot(dsamp, aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = clarity)))

 d + scale_colour_brewer()
```